# Как сделать отправку писем только с одной формы?

Tags: php, wordpress, telegram-bot, contact-form7

Есть такой код, который отправляет значения полей из Contact Form 7 в телеграм.
Но особенность в том, что теперь отправляются данные из всех форм, и в чат прилетают заявки с пустыми полями.

Нужно сделать так, чтобы форма только с определенным id отправлялась в телеграм

Сделал вот такой код, но он не работает((

```
function cf7_send_tg_hosting( $contact_form, $abort, $submission ) {
   $form_id = $contact_form->posted_data['_wpcf7'];
   $wpcf->skip_mail = false;  # Отключаем отправку письма на эмейл
   $name2 = $submission->get_posted_data('your-name-hosting');  # Название поля Имя
   $email2 = $submission->get_posted_data('your-email-hosting');  # Название поля Эмейл
   $tel2 = $submission->get_posted_data('tel-652-hosting');  # Название поля Телефон
   $subject2 = $submission->get_posted_data('your-subject-hosting');  # Название поля Темы
   $mess2 = $submission->get_posted_data('your-message-hosting');  # Название поля Сообщение
   $type_hosting = $submission->get_posted_data('mine-type');  # Название поля Сообщение
   $price_hosting = $submission->get_posted_data('mine-price');  # Название поля Сообщение
   $msg = '*Заявка на хостинг*'; 
   $msg .= 'Имя: '.$name2.'';
   $msg .= 'Телефон: '.$tel2.''; 
   $msg .= 'Цена: '.$price_hosting.' руб'.'';  
   $msg .= 'Тип: '.$type_hosting.'';   
   $userId = 'xxx'; // id user, которому отправляем письмо
   $token = 'xxx'; // Token бота 
   file_get_contents('https://api.telegram.org/bot'. $token .'/sendMessage?chat_id='. $userId .'&text=' . urlencode($msg) . '&parse_mode=markdown');
}  
// add the action 
if ($form_id = 1610) {
   add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'cf7_send_tg_hosting', 10, 3 );
   
}
```

Специально скрыл токен и id

Спасибо!

Comment: `if ($form_id = 1610)` -- это присваивание, а не сравнение. Используйте равенство `==` или строгое равенство `===`.

Comment: Ну и собственно, разве `$form_id` доступно вне функции `cf7_send_tg_hosting()`? Проверку и все остальное нужно делать внутри ее, а не вне.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это можно сделать вот так

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'cf7_send_tg_hosting', 10, 3 );

function cf7_send_tg_hosting( $contact_form, $abort, $submission ) {
    $form_id = $contact_form->id();

    if ( $form_id != 1610 ) {  // 1610 это id формы с которой вы будете отправлять сообщение
        return;
    }

    // здесь будет ваш код для отправки сообщения в тг
}
```